# Regex to extract just a portion of the base filename

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm pretty new to regex and I'm trying to get the portion of a base filename to reuse later in a variable. I'm running tests with echo in order to see the output but I haven't been able to get it to work how I expect. This is the piece of code I've come up with.

```
#!/bin/bash
search_dir=/var/FTP/DB
filter="[^_0-9.ra]"
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  echo $(basename $entry) #| grep -oP $filter
done
```

It successfully takes the part of the base filename I want but it's splitting each letter in a new line. Can someone help me get this straighten out?

```
EDIT:
File in /var/FTP/DB:
TEXT_04-20-20-15-55.zip
LEARN_03-22-19-00-01.rar

Desired output:
TEXT
LEARN
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I've edited my question to include an example input|output

Comment: grep is generally used to match pattern and output what is matched.  sed is generally used to stream edit.  PERL is generally used for reformatting.

Comment: @vantech : You tagged this as _bash_ and _shell_. You can't do regexp in POSIX shell. You can do it in bash, using the `=~` operator, i.e. `if [[ $variable =~ regexp ]]`. Have a look at the section labelled _Compound Commands_ in the bash man page. It also describes how to extract the parts matched by the regexp.

Comment: @vanttech: BTW, for your simple example, regexp matching is an overkill. Globbing (wildcard matching) is most likely sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

search_dir=.
filter="_.*$";

for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
    echo $(basename $entry) | sed -e "s/$filter//"
done
```